# What is the integrity field in the npm package-lock.json actually for?

Tags: npm

I'm poking around in npm at the moment. I am trying to see what sort of security risks there are to developers using npm.

The main sort of attack I'm interested in are supply chain attacks where either a developer or a build system (which we can consider just another developer) get something they don't expect.

I have unexpected - at least for me - behaviour when I do the following:

- `npm init`
- `npm install xxx` - doesn't matter what xxx is
- Edit the package-lock.json file and alter the integrity - e.g. change one char
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm install`

**EXPECT**
Some sort of complaint that the installed package's hash doesn't match

**ACTUAL**
package-lock.json just gets updated

Am I being dense here? I'm expecting the integrity field to cause npm to somehow spot when something unexpected is installed. Why does it just get updated?

Comment: I tested with both `npm@7` and `npm@6` and got an `EINTEGRITY` error both times. What version of npm are you running, what operating system, and are you installing the package from the public repository or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm perplexed. I can't repro now. Naively I ended up switching versions of node using nvm after starting to answer your question. Unfortunately I didn't try to repo before I did that so I can't say for certain whether switching versions (and switching back) changed the behaviour. I'll close the post. Not sure how to explain this other than wetware failure :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

I tested with both `npm@7` and `npm@6` and got an `EINTEGRITY` error both times. I installed Node.js 10.x and tested with `npm@5` and again got `EINTEGRITY`. Prior to `npm@5`, there was no `package-lock.json` file supported.

I can think of two scenarios (other than "I forgot to save my changes in package-lock.json" and stuff like that) that might explain what you are seeing.

First, perhaps you are accidentally removing `package-lock.json` when removing `node_modules`? I mean, I remove both together so often that there's a potential muscle memory issue for me. Maybe you have the same?

The only other thing I can come up with is if you initially installed using a version of `npm` that supports `package-lock.json` but then after editing `package-lock.json`, you re-installed using a version prior to the introduction of the `package-lock.json` feature. That seems unlikely, but is possible if you are using different interactive shells for the installs and using `nvm`. Open two terminals, change the version of `node` and `npm` in one terminal, and then use both terminals--you are now using different versions in the two terminals.